# Parsing current location from a bash script when sourcing another script

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash script that is saved in a location included in my `PATH` variable. Within this script I need to source another script that is saved in a different location. In my first (main) script I change directory to the location of this second script and then I source it.

```
cd $path_of_2nd_script && source 2nd_script
```

The problem is that in my second script (the one that is sourced) I have some variables that need to retrieve the location of the second script with `dirname $0`. The problem is that is retrieving the location of the first script (`$path_of_1st_script`), not the `$path_of_2nd_script` where I changed directory in my main script, just before sourcing it. How can I pass the `path_of_2nd_script` into `2nd_script`? Does it make sense?

Comment: If you need your CWD to be at your first script, can you just source the second script without using cd? `source $path_of_2nd_script/2nd_script`?

Comment: @RobertSeaman That's the problem, I need my CWD to be at the 2nd script but is getting the the path from the first one with `dirname $0`

Answer (score 0):

Change `source 2nd_script` to e.g. `bash 2nd_script`. When using `source`, the argument will be executed in the current shell environment, which means that `$0` will refer to the first script.

Comment: That could actually work but how I pass all the env variables from my `1st_script` into the `2nd_script`

Comment: You will have to `export` them

Comment: @sneep That's not what exporting does. Exporting makes variables available to *child* processes (i.e. processes run from the script doing the exporting), not to the *parent* process (the one that ran the script).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ah, I guess I didn't think of the possibility that they'd modify the variables in the child script. @Birbal, are you going to modify the variables in the child script? If yes, `export` will not help you, as these modifications will not stick

Comment: @sneep Is a bit more complicated than that...I just tried to simplify the problem here...the parent script is actually souring another bash script at the beginning that sets up some variables...these vars has to be available to all the scripts that are called from the parent script (including the parent) but I don't need to modify them.

Comment: Then exporting the variables from `1st_script` for `2nd_script` will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you are sourcing your second script rather than executing as a child process, in which case `$0` would resolve to the name of the second script itself.

If you could change the second script to grab its directory from its `$1` and then change the first script this way:

```
cd "$path_of_2nd_script" && source 2nd_script "$path_of_2nd_script"
```